# Programmatically dismiss modal dialog in Bootstrap and display another page on submit

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

When a user goes to a page that requires them to register, I want to display a Bootstrap modal dialog with id and password. When the user presses the submit button, I want to:

1. Validate the password and sign them up
2. Dismiss the dialog
3. Take them to another page to display some information

What happens currently is when the user presses the Submit button. I go through the validation and try to hide the Bootstrap modal dialog, but then the page re-displays and the dialog comes back. This happens over and over again.

Here is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ppk007/9kLbrc5a/14/)

Here is the HTML page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta
      name="viewport"
      content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no"
    />

    <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
      integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script
      src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script
      src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>

    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Immedia Signup</title>

    <script src="https://npmcdn.com/parse/dist/parse.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
    <!-- Immedia stylsheet overrides -->
    <!-- <link href="css/im-styles.css" rel="stylesheet" /> -->

    <style>
      html,
      body {
        background: url() no-repeat center center fixed;
        -webkit-background-size: cover;
        -moz-background-size: cover;
        -o-background-size: cover;
        background-size: cover;
        /* color: #212529; */
        /* color: #bccee0; */
        color: #bccee0;
      }

      .big-text-on-bg-img {
        width: 75%;
        padding-right: 15px;
        padding-left: 15px;
        margin-right: auto;
        margin-left: auto;
        font-size: 2.5rem;
        font-weight: 400;
        line-height: 1.2;
      }

      @media (min-width: 450px) {
        .container-xs {
          max-width: 500px;
        }
      }

      .display-5 {
        font-size: 2.5rem;
        font-weight: 300;
        line-height: 1.2;
      }
    </style>
    <title>Immedia Home</title>
  </head>
  <body onload="onloadHandler()">
    <div class="cover-container d-flex w-100 h-100 p-3 mx-auto flex-column">
      <header class="masthead mb-auto">
        <div class="inner">
          <h1 class="masthead-brand">Modal Test Page</h1>
        </div>
      </header>
    </div>
    <!-- cover-container -->
    <!-- Modal -->
    <div
      class="modal fade"
      id="signupModal"
      data-backdrop="static"
      tabindex="-1"
      role="dialog"
      aria-labelledby="signupModalLabel"
      aria-hidden="true"
    >
      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="signup-title">
              Thanks for entering an email address and password to protect your
              account.
            </h5>
          </div>
          <!-- modal-header -->
          <div class="modal-body">
            <form id="signup-form" onsubmit="submitHandler()">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="email">Email address</label>
                <input
                  type="email"
                  autocomplete="username"
                  class="form-control"
                  id="email"
                  aria-describedby="emailHelp"
                  required
                />
                <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted"
                  >We'll never spam you or share your email.</small
                >
              </div>
              <!-- form-group -->
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="password">Password</label>
                <input
                  type="password"
                  autocomplete="new-password"
                  class="form-control"
                  id="pwd-field"
                  aria-describedby="passwordHelp"
                  required
                />
                <small id="passwordHelp" class="form-text text-muted">
                  Passwords must have at least 8 characters with one uppercase
                  one lowercase, one digit and one special character
                  "!@#$%&amp;*()"
                </small>
              </div>
              <!-- form-group -->
              <div class="form-group">
                <button
                  id="submit-button"
                  type="submit"
                  class="btn btn-primary"
                >
                  Submit
                </button>
              </div>
              <!-- form-group -->
            </form>
          </div>
          <!-- modal-body -->
        </div>
        <!-- modal-content -->
      </div>
      <!-- modal-dialog -->
    </div>
    <!-- modal fade-->

    <!-- JavaScript -->
    <script>
      // Function definitions
      //

      $("#signupModal").on("hidden.bs.modal", function() {
        $("body").removeClass("signupModal");
      });

      // Hide a DOM element on the page
      // Process the signup when the user presses submit
      $("#submit-button").click(function() {
        const email = $("#email").val();
        const password = $("#pwd-field").val();
        console.info("email: " + email + ', password: "' + password + '"');

        if (true) {
          // Do not check for valid password. Assume it is for now.
          console.info("valid password: ", password);

          try {
            // Signup user here
            console.info("submitHandler(): successfully signed up");
            $("#signupModal").modal(hide);
            // They signed up successfully. Send them to the next page (for example only)
            window.location.href = "https://www.duckduckgo.com";
         } catch (err) {
            console.error("Error signing up: ", err);
          }
        } else {
          // invalid password
          $("#pwd-field").val("");
        }
        console.info("submitHandler(): exiting function");
      });

      // Begin page execution
      function onloadHandler() {
        console.info("onloadHandler()");
        $("body").addClass("#signupModal");
        $("#signupModal").modal("toggle");
     }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you use the sign up process to also sign them in? If not, perhaps attach their IP address to the sign up request to temporarily stop the modal.

Comment: Actually, I am doing exactly that. I'm signing them up, and logging them in. Can you elaborate on how attaching the IP address would stop the modal? Thanks.

Comment: do a validation where if the current user's ip address matches the ip address that is attached to the sign up process, they will not be asked to sign up again.

Comment: Do you have anything (session/storage) that indicates the user is signed in? You could use this to decide whether to show the modal `if (!signed_in) { ...show modal }`

Comment: The problem is not with showing the modal. I already have session information to decide when to show the modal. The problem is when the user presses submit. The modal goes away momentarily and the page refreshes and the modal *COMES BACK* even though I'm hiding the modal in button click handler. In the click handler, I want to hide/remove/destroy the modal. I have tried at least 4 different solutions and none seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are clicking on a submit button inside a `form`. This will trigger a `form submit` where it attempts to redirect the submit request. since you have not specified any `action` and `method` attributes on the `form` tag, the browser does not know where to redirect the `form submit` request and you see a blank page.

In your code you have specified an action listener using js on the submit button. The code inside the listener will execute and after this the default action i.e. the `form submit` will execute. To prevent this add `e.preventDefault()` and the `form submit` event is not executed.

Below code works. You will get a blank page with console error **Refused to display 'https://duckduckgo.com/' in a frame because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-ancestors 'self'"** while running the code in jsfiddle or stackoverflow snippet. This shows the page redirect happened correctly and will work in your application. SO and JSFiddle doesnt like to display other websites within its code snippets.

```js
$("#signupModal").on("hidden.bs.modal", function() {
  $("body").removeClass("signupModal");
});

// Hide a DOM element on the page
// Process the signup when the user presses submit
$("#submit-button").click(function(e) {
  // ************Add below code to prevent defauilt submit button form submit **********
  e.preventDefault();
  const email = $("#email").val();
  const password = $("#pwd-field").val();
  console.info("email: " + email + ', password: "' + password + '"');

  if (true) {
    // Do not check for valid password. Assume it is for now.
    console.info("valid password: ", password);

    try {
      // Signup user here
      console.info("submitHandler(): successfully signed up");
      $("#signupModal").modal('hide');
      // They signed up successfully. Send them to the next page (for example only)
      // ************ Change code to replace so that register page is removed from browser history on redirect **********
      window.location.replace("https://www.duckduckgo.com");
    } catch (err) {
      console.error("Error signing up: ", err);
    }
  } else {
    // invalid password
    $("#pwd-field").val("");
  }
  console.info("submitHandler(): exiting function");
});

// Begin page execution
function onloadHandler() {
  console.info("onloadHandler()");
  $("body").addClass("#signupModal");
  $("#signupModal").modal("toggle");
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  background: url() no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  /* color: #212529; */
  /* color: #bccee0; */
  color: #bccee0;
}

.big-text-on-bg-img {
  width: 75%;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.2;
}

@media (min-width: 450px) {
  .container-xs {
    max-width: 500px;
  }
}

.display-5 {
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  font-weight: 300;
  line-height: 1.2;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
  <title>Immedia Signup</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://npmcdn.com/parse/dist/parse.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous" />
  <!-- Immedia stylsheet overrides -->
  <!-- <link href="css/im-styles.css" rel="stylesheet" /> -->
</head>

<body onload="onloadHandler()">
  <div class="cover-container d-flex w-100 h-100 p-3 mx-auto flex-column">
    <header class="masthead mb-auto">
      <div class="inner">
        <h1 class="masthead-brand">Modal Test Page</h1>
      </div>
    </header>
  </div>
  <!-- cover-container -->
  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="signupModal" data-backdrop="static" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="signupModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="signup-title">
            Thanks for entering an email address and password to protect your account.
          </h5>
        </div>
        <!-- modal-header -->
        <div class="modal-body">
          <!-- ************ Remove form submit code ***********-->
          <form id="signup-form">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="email">Email address</label>
              <input type="email" autocomplete="username" class="form-control" id="email" aria-describedby="emailHelp" required />
              <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never spam you or share your email.</small
                    >
                  </div>
                  <!-- form-group -->
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="password">Password</label>
                    <input
                      type="password"
                      autocomplete="new-password"
                      class="form-control"
                      id="pwd-field"
                      aria-describedby="passwordHelp"
                      required
                    />
                    <small id="passwordHelp" class="form-text text-muted">
                      Passwords must have at least 8 characters with one uppercase
                      one lowercase, one digit and one special character
                      "!@#$%&amp;*()"
                    </small>
            </div>
            <!-- form-group -->
            <div class="form-group">
              <button id="submit-button" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                      Submit
                    </button>
            </div>
            <!-- form-group -->
          </form>
        </div>
        <!-- modal-body -->
      </div>
      <!-- modal-content -->
    </div>
    <!-- modal-dialog -->
  </div>
  <!-- modal fade-->
</body>

</html>
```